# Mysql query for concatenate unknown number of values in a new field

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have a table with two fields (Job ID, Employee name). 
I want to concatenate all the employee names in one field. 
Each job has at least one employee, and I prefer to have a comma or any other separators between the employees.

An example can be like this: 
(Input)

```
J#  Employee name
1   Cathrine
1   Sami
1   Jack
2   Jack
2   John
3   Afshin
```

(output)

```
J#  Employee names
1   Cathrine, Sami, Jack
2   Jack, John
3   Afshin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use group concat with SEPARATOR expression.

```
SELECT 
   `job_id` as `Job Id`,
   GROUP_CONCAT(`employee_name` SEPARATOR ", ") AS `Employee Names`
FROM
   `TABLE1`
GROUP BY
    `job_id`
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to group on the job id, and use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to concatenate all the grouped values for a field.

`SELECT job_id AS 'J#', GROUP_CONCAT(employee_name) AS 'Employee names' FROM some_table GROUP BY job_id`